# Vue JS sort and then return to previous state

Tags: vue.js

I have a set of results in my Vue app. I want to be able to sort them alphabetically after I have searched. I then want them to return to the state before I clicked 'alphabetically' also. In my case its relevancy.

Relevancy is how it loads and before I choose 'Alphabetically'

The alphabetical option works fine but when I change it back to 'relevancy' it doesnt do anything and I dont understand why. To me it should just be  'return this.results();'

Can anyone help please?

```
<select
                class="form-control col-4 col-lg-5"
                v-model="sortatoz"
                @change="sortItems"
                id="sortby"
                aria-label="sortby"
              >
                <option disabled value="" selected>Select</option>
                <option value="alphabetically">Alphabetically</option>
                <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
              </select>

//sort drop down
    sortItems() {
      if (this.sortatoz === "alphabetically") {
        return this.results.sort((a, b) =>
          a.title > b.title ? 1 : -1
        );
      } else {
         return this.results();
       
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, you copy your original set into a data variable you going to show inside your HTML.

So whenever you sort, you use this copied variable to sort.
But whenever you want relevance again, you just copy the original again in the copied variable.

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  list: ['A', 'C', 'B'],
  copiedList: []
  },
 mounted () {
  this.unsort()
 },
 methods: {     
  sort() {
   this.copiedList = [...this.list].sort((a, b) =>
          a > b ? 1 : -1
        );
  },
   unsort() {
   this.copiedList = [...this.list]
  }           
}
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
<button @click="sort">Sort</button>
<button @click="unsort">Unsort</button>

 <div v-for="element in copiedList">
  <div> {{ element }} </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you could help with some code, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I made an edit :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Wimanicesir . I see this works in your example perfectly. It does not work for me, unfortunately. I cant really understand why though. If the 'if' part of my statement works well why doesn't the 'else' part?

Comment: If you are talking about your example in your question. It does not work because you mutate this.list with the sort function. So your 'else part' just returns that same sorted list.
If you are talking about new code, I can not know what went wrong, you could edit your question and add new code :)

Comment: So in my code, how could I address the 'else' part which does not work? Can I just revert back in the 'else' part? Is that possible?. The list loads initially by relevance. Thanks for your help also.

Comment: I can not emphasize enough that 'sort()' directly changes the array. As quoted from the documentation: 'The return value is the reference to the original array, now sorted. Note that the array is sorted in place, and no copy is made.' So if you want to keep the original, you have to make a copy of your own :) (That's what [...list] does, making a copy of that array)

Comment: No problem! At last I would really advise you to understand the difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy. This article might help: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd/

Comment: Very interesting reading, thank you! One more question I have, if I may. The results don't display on the page until I click one of the buttons. How can I just get the results to show onload? Should it be in the mounted property?

Comment: Yes ofcourse! I made an edit where it also happens :)

Comment: Great, this works well in the example but I cant get it to work on my example! It gives me something to work with though which is great. Thanks again!

Comment: Im still having the issue whereby the results do not display when the page loads. They only display when a selection has been made by the sort method. I have tried adding it the the 'mounted' code but still no joy. Any ideas what this may be?

Comment: Without code it's hard to help you. I would advise you to make a new question with the focus on this new problem. This comments thread is becoming way too long and your current question about sort is already answered.

Comment: okay, i will do thank you.